# how to exclude one subdomain from subdomains that share SESSION variable

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain, cookieless

I had a cookie-free subdomain (static) until I used this code to make my session variable visible in all sub-domains:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','.example.com');
```

apparently, By doing so, I have lost cookie-free characteristic of the "static" subdomain.

How could I have one session variable visible in  all subdomains except the static one?
thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having similar problem as you, and I think my solution will help you for your cookie-less static domain. I've described my issue and subsequent solution below so hopefully you can use it to solve your issue.

I wanted to share the session on 2 subdomains:

- www.example.com
- shop.example.com

But exclude that session, and use its own session on

- admin.example.com

To set the session to be used across the two domains, as you described you will have to set the cookie params:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','.example.com');
```

However, this will conflict with the cookie for the admin.example.com session.

The solution is to set the **session name** in the admin site so it differs to the session name in the other sites. For example:

```
session_name("AdminPHPSESSID");
```

See http://www.php.net/session_name for more info.

Answer (score 1):

can you please set in php.ini file

The domain for which the cookie is valid.

```
session.cookie_domain = "domain"
```

OR

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
```

Comment: it have several domains which share session but just one domain to exclude. should I write session.cookie_domain = "domain" for all sharing subdomains?