# PHP cookie for only specific subdomains

Tags: php, subdomain, session-cookies

I have a session cookie being set that works on all my subdomains:

`session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.my-cool-domain.com');`

This sends cookies for all my subdomains including my CDS subdomain, which I don't want.

Is it possible to set ONLY specific subs? Something like:

`session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.my-cool-domain.com,app.my-cool-domain.com');`

Don't want to use a different domain to avoid purchasing another ssl cert.
Any other solutions welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973386/how-to-exclude-one-subdomain-from-subdomains-that-share-session-variable